# Captive Wi-Fi to Regular Wi-Fi bridge solution

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge, wifi-configuration, captive-portal

I'm looking for a software / hardware solution to my issue - I have free access to Wi-Fi in my building but it requires browser login (i.e. captive network). I want to use a streamer on this network that does not support captive networks (Apple TV), a gaming console (PS4) - looking for a solution to create my own regular WPA2 secured Wi-Fi SSID in the apartment which is essentially "riding" on the captive Wi-Fi signal and that the bridge device will handle the browser login for all other devices. I found many solutions online for captive wired to wireless bridge but not one captive wireless to wireless bridge solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After authenticating with the captive network, how long does your connection last? Do you need to re-authenticate every day? Week? Or is it permanent?

Comment: I am 99% sure it's permanent.

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer, but what you want then is a device that can use a wifi gateway. You authenticate on a "real" device, then spoof that devices MAC address. The catch is that spoofed device can not appear on the WiFi network then, unless you change its MAC, as you can't have two devices with the same MAC in the wifi.

Comment: Is there a router device that supports that? I tried spoofing the Apple TV MAC address using the laptop connect authenticate and then disconnect and connect the real Apple TV device. It worked for few minutes and then lost internet connectivity.

Comment: Odd. It might use some cookie checking or something. But then anything that wasn't a web browser wouldn't work over the network. Or maybe it does user-agent checking. You might be out of luck...

Comment: Maybe it's not permanent as I think. MacBook and iPad etc have that "auto login" option checked for this network. What about a router with dd-wrt? I know it has many custom features but I lack the expertise on that.

Comment: A good amazon search is "travel router",   I have a wired to wifi version i've used for a few years,  i've been thinking about upgrading it, because wifi or wired to wifi now exists.  You just provide the login to the captive network on one device, so other devices like apple tv, PS4 just get network once you login via laptop browser.

Comment: Which device is that? Do I need to install dd-wrt on it to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be as complicated as some of the comments are suggesting. You just have to connect to that captive portal's Wi-Fi network on your computer, and then turn on Internet connection sharing, or NAT routing, or whatever your operating system calls it on your computer. Then you can get connectivity through the Ethernet port on your computer. You can even plug in your own Wi-Fi access point in to that Ethernet port to make your own Wi-Fi network. To get through the captive portal, just use the browser on your computer, or any other device that has a web browser that is connected through your computer can do it too.

You could even share it through an second wireless card in ad-hoc mode on your computer.